# How much current is drawn by an 18,600 BTU A/C compressor during free run?

Tags: power, amperage

I recently got an old hermetic A/C compressor. I plan to use this as a vacuum pump mostly for some of my hobby projects. The specs on the label on the A/C said that it power draw is 2450 Watts, 11.5Amps.

Does it mean that the current draw is 11.5 Amps always or is it only while there is some load on the compressor like while it is compressing some refrigerant or gas? Also I noticed that the compressor isn't very loud while its outside compared to when it was inside the A/C it was quite loud.

Also I heard that the compressor oil gets acidic while exposed to air. Is it true?[image: Compressor specs]

Comment: Power draw will of course vary depending on the mode of operation and load.  This is a site only for fully documentable engineering design questions - most questions about consumer products, including this one are off topic here.  A primary reason why they cannot be handled here is that a question such as yours is entirely dependent on internal implementation detail which has not been specified.

Comment: Current is for breaker power budget only . Starting may be 300% or more.  And less in with light load. Noise is from excess heat , Freon converts to diluted Nitric acid condensation with air and corrodes everything. Which reminds when I was 12 deicing with a hammer and pick

Comment: As noted the label tells you about breaker power/current …..but for a compressor power consumption it's either ON or OFF, there is no light load. The blower may be on a variable (typically high, medium or low) setting, but not the compressor.

Comment: @ChrisStratton sorry if the question is off topic. I asked this question here because I found it difficult to get good info on the amp ratings on hermetic compressors. I was hoping since we have lot of experienced wise members here, they might be able to help me.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt I read somewhere a while back they have something like starting wattage that is a lot higher than there running wattage like you mentioned. So, is the wattage in the label is running wattage right? As of now the compressor is removed from the A/C. There is no freon. The gas has be refilled only thrice in all these years, I don't know if they ever changed the oil during the service in theses three years. So, if there is no freon then the oil wouldn't be acidic?

Comment: @JackCreasey Yes, I'm aware that the compressor load doesn't change when the speed settings are changed, only the fan speed as you said. What I meant was when the compressor isn't filled with a pressurized gas like freon and the inlet and discharge tubes are fully exposed to air the compressor noise is almost like a small toy motor. But back when it was filled with freon and it was way louder.

Comment: no gas then no load  Too much noise? worn out moving parts when hot and chamber expands

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt Thanks. I can agree with that. It's 26 years old so its probably ready to give up it's ghost anytime. But since its U.S made I still have some hopes.

Comment: @thevintage At most 20 Amp, says right on the plate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does mean that using the nominal load it draws 11.5 Amps.

If it is an air conditioner the load is 18600 BTU / hours, which is 5.6kW -> the thermal energy it can draw out.

However, when you use the motor don't drive it more than 11.5 Amps in long term.

[image]

The figure above shows a typical torque - motor speed diagram.

If you have no load, the motor speed will be higher, because only cooper, iron and friction losses determines the motor current. For higher load, the output power increase, resulting in a higher motor current (~ I_motor * V) and the motor speed decrease.

BTW:

[image]

So I would estimate, since it seems to be an older motor, that is draw **~2 Amps** during free run. (efficency of 80%)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the it might include the little wattage of the fan too. I think it dragged about 1.8 - 2 Amps.

Comment: the motor will draw about 2 Amps I think, with your fan you have about: 4 Amps. Does it really have an extra fan? Most motors at that size have the fan on the drive shaft, which increases of course the torque.